# string to date using php or mysql

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Can anyone please help me how to convert string to date

I have 3 dropdowns(year,month,date)and i got date value as 2012-january-12.

How can i convert it like 2012-01-12(yyyy-mm-dd).

$dob = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

I used str_to_date('$dob','%Y-%M-%e') in the query itself but its stops executing the query.

Here is the query

```
      $sql = "insert into issio_asc_workers (lname_fname_dob, asc_id, asc_lastname, asc_firstname, asc_middlename, asc_dob, asc_phone_mobile, asc_phone_work, asc_ssn,
              asc_email, asc_phone_preferred, asc_status, asc_emp_yesno, asc_emp_status, asc_user_type, asc_npi, asc_credentials, asc_committee, asc_speciality, 
              asc_group, asc_startdate)values ('$lfd', '$ascid', '$lname', '$fname', '$mname', 
             'str_to_date('$dob','%Y-%M-%e')', '$phCell', '$phOffice', '$ssn', '$email', '$preffered', '$asc_status', '$empType', '$asc_emp_status', '$asc_user_type', '$npi', 
             '$credential', '$commitee ', '$speciality', '$group', 'str_to_date('$sdate','%Y-%M-%e')')";
```

Thnaks In advance....,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to marshall your variables before you insert them into your sql query. This is no more difficult for the program to run, but makes your life as a programmer much easier:

```
$dob_asDate = str_to_date('$dob','%Y-%M-%e');

$sql = "insert into issio_asc_workers (lname_fname_dob, asc_id, asc_lastname, asc_firstname, asc_middlename, asc_dob, asc_phone_mobile, asc_phone_work, asc_ssn,
              asc_email, asc_phone_preferred, asc_status, asc_emp_yesno, asc_emp_status, asc_user_type, asc_npi, asc_credentials, asc_committee, asc_speciality, 
              asc_group, asc_startdate)values ('$lfd', '$ascid', '$lname', '$fname', '$mname', 
             '$dob_asDate', '$phCell', '$phOffice', '$ssn', '$email', '$preffered', '$asc_status', '$empType', '$asc_emp_status', '$asc_user_type', '$npi', 
             '$credential', '$commitee ', '$speciality', '$group', 'str_to_date('$sdate','%Y-%M-%e')')";
```

This way you can echo `$dob_asDate` and ensure it's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', '2010-06-03T14:29:00');
```

Try this... Fill in the date with your information received from the form, then put the variable in the MySQL Insert query